# Is pyautocad needs a running autoCad Software?

Tags: python, python-3.x, autocad

I am getting an error . when I try to convert dwg AutoCAD file to excel.
I used http://www.run8tech.com/script-to-update-text-and-mtext-in-autocad-from-excel.aspx
I am getting an error

this is the script I ran. Is autocad running is necessary for using this library pyautocad

```
from __future__ import print_function
from os.path import join, dirname, abspath
from xlutils.copy import copy
import xlrd
import xlwt 
from pyautocad import Autocad, APoint
import os
import win32com.client
from pyautocad import Autocad, APoint
from pyautocad.contrib.tables import Table
#Create workbook
book = xlwt.Workbook()
ws = book.add_sheet("ExportedData")
book.save("Exported.xls")

#Open the workbook
xl_workbook = xlrd.open_workbook("Exported.xls")
sheet_names = xl_workbook.sheet_names()

xl_sheet = xl_workbook.sheet_by_name(sheet_names[0])

wb = copy(xl_workbook)
sheet = wb.get_sheet(0)

dwgfiles = filter(os.path.isfile, os.listdir( os.curdir ) )

cwd = os.path.abspath(os.path.curdir) #current working dir

for f in dwgfiles:
  print(f)
  if f.endswith(".dwg"):
      print("sdaasdas")
      """ open Document"""
      acad = Autocad()
      print(cwd)
      acad.doc.Open(cwd + "/" + f)

      print (acad.doc.Name)

      num_cols = xl_sheet.ncols   # Number of columns
      idx = 1

      acad = win32com.client.Dispatch("AutoCAD.Application")

      doc = acad.ActiveDocument   # Document object


      print ("MODEL SPACE")

      for entity in acad.ActiveDocument.ModelSpace:
          name = entity.EntityName
          print(name)
          if name == 'AcDbText':
              sheet.row(idx).write(0,entity.TextString) 
              sheet.row(idx).write(1,entity.ObjectID)
              sheet.row(idx).write(2,cwd + "/" + f)
              idx = idx + 1
          if name == 'AcDbBlockReference':
              HasAttributes = entity.HasAttributes
              if HasAttributes:
                #  print(entity.Name)
             #     print(entity.Layer)
              #    print(entity.ObjectID)
                  for attrib in entity.GetAttributes():

                      if attrib.TagString != "DATA":
                          sheet.row(idx).write(0,attrib.TextString ) 
                          sheet.row(idx).write(1,entity.ObjectID)
                          sheet.row(idx).write(2,cwd + "/" + f)
                          idx = idx + 1



      print ("PAPER SPACE")
      for entity in acad.ActiveDocument.PaperSpace:
          name = entity.EntityName
          if name == 'AcDbText':
              sheet.row(idx).write(0,entity.TextString) 
              sheet.row(idx).write(1,entity.ObjectID)
              sheet.row(idx).write(2,cwd + "/" + f)
              idx = idx + 1
          if name == 'AcDbBlockReference':
              HasAttributes = entity.HasAttributes
              if HasAttributes:
                #  print(entity.Name)
             #     print(entity.Layer)
              #    print(entity.ObjectID)
                  for attrib in entity.GetAttributes():

                      if attrib.TagString != "DATA":
                          sheet.row(idx).write(0,attrib.TextString ) 
                          sheet.row(idx).write(1,entity.ObjectID)
                          sheet.row(idx).write(2,cwd + "/" + f)


                      idx = idx + 1



      doc.Close(False)
      acad = None
wb.save("Exported.xls")
```

when I run this script error I am getting is this

```
File "test.py", line 36, in <module>
  acad.doc.Open(cwd + "/" + f)
File "C:\Users\nithish\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\pyautocad\api.py", line 74, in doc
  return self.app.ActiveDocument
File "C:\Users\nithish\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\pyautocad\api.py", line 63, in app
  self._app = comtypes.client.GetActiveObject('AutoCAD.Application', dynamic=True)
File "C:\Users\nithish\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\comtypes\client\__init__.py", line 173, in GetActiveObject
  clsid = comtypes.GUID.from_progid(progid)
File "C:\Users\nithish\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\comtypes\GUID.py", line 78, in from_progid
  _CLSIDFromProgID(str(progid), byref(inst))
File "_ctypes/callproc.c", line 933, in GetResult
OSError: [WinError -2147221005] Invalid class string
```

Comment: Nope, you need not run AutoCAD. But make sure to install it properly.

Comment: @Arnie97 Still getting error after installing AutoCAD

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would get the error:

> OSError: [WinError -2147221005] Invalid class string

If

1. You don't have AutoCAD installed
2. If you have a version installed, but are trying to instantiate the wrong version like: `CreateObject("Autocad19.Application")` when you have AutoCAD20 installed.

In general, libraries leave the version number out, so "Autocad.Application" would work fine.

The call to `Autocad()` will start an instance of AutoCAD if it is installed.

Comment: D:\autocad_files
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 37, in <module>
    acad.doc.Open(cwd + "/" + f)
  File "C:\Users\nithish\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\comtypes\client\lazybind.py", line 182, in caller
    return self._comobj._invoke(descr.memid, descr.invkind, 0, *args)
  File "C:\Users\nithish\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\comtypes\automation.py", line 729, in _invoke
    dp, var, None, argerr)
_ctypes.COMError: (-2147352567, 'Exception occurred.', ('', 'AutoCAD', None, 0, None)) Now i getting this error

Comment: what is the value of cwd at that time?

Comment: D:\autocad_files  @reckface

Comment: File "C:\Users\nithish\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\comtypes\automation.py", line 729, in _invoke
    dp, var, None, argerr)
_ctypes.COMError: (-2147352567, 'Exception occurred.', ('Method not available in MDI mode. Use Open method of Documents collection.', 'AutoCAD', 'C:\\Program Files\\Autodesk\\AutoCAD 2019\\HELP\\OLE_ERR.CHM', -2145320848, None))

Comment: There's no  acad.doc.open method. You want acad.Documents.Open(filename)

Comment: D:\autocad_files
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 37, in <module>
    acad.Documents.Open(cwd + "/" + f)
AttributeError: 'Autocad' object has no attribute 'Documents'

Comment: @NithishAlbin one last thing to try: acad.app.Documents.open

Answer (score 0):

Here is my environment:

1. AutoCAD: AutoCAD Civil 3D 2018
2. Python: Python 3.8.2
3. OS: Windows 10

I passed the create_if_not_exists argument of pyautocad.Autocad to True. Then the code started working without problem.
So try doing this:

```py
acad = Autocad(create_if_not_exists=True)
```